# Phone usb driver?

Tags: usb, phone, usb-drive

LG has no support for a linux driver at this time for my phone.  Nor will they because its an older phone.  Ubuntu doesn't recognize my phone it just charges it.  I tried using bitpim to access my phone but no ports are available.  I believe I need some kind of driver.  I've googled everywhere i can't seem to find anything.

Phone info- 
LG revere- Non smart phone
CDMA

What I would like to do:
1. Access entire file tree (Not sure if this is possible)
Pretty much it not really into transferring ringtones or pictures to or from it.  Also i want to be able to see the spc because it isn't the default with 0's

Comment: Please provide USB ID for this device. (extract from output of **lsusb**). *Or, is it not recognised as a USB device?*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, provide us with a little bit more information: What kind of phone do you use? Is it a smartphone? Do you need certain tools that should work, like fastboot or do you want to use it only for sending data to your PC and vice versa?